# How do I get a float/double bits without doing undefined behavour?

Tags: c++

In C++ I want to get the bits of `double myval = 1.3;` It's 0x3FF4CCCCCCCCCCCC however how do I get it without breaking alias rules and doing undefined behavior?

Answer (score 4):

You can copy the bits into an integer object byte by byte. Aliasing with `char` is allowed. Then you can shift and mask the bits of that integer to get values of individual bits.

The easiest way to copy byte by byte is `std::memcpy`. You'll need to make sure that your integer type is large enough.

```
double myval = 1.3;
unsigned long long myval_int = 0;
static_assert(sizeof myval_int == sizeof myval);
std::memcpy(&myval_int, &myval, sizeof myval);
std::cout << std::hex << myval_int;
```

For a better way to make sure that you've got appropriately sized integer type, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/integer.html

Note that copying to into the beginning of the integer works only if the integer has the same size - or if integer is larger, then CPU has to be little endian. If integer is larger, and CPU is big endian, then you need to copy with an offset.

Comment: static assert seems like the best way and that doesn't require boost

Comment: @acidzombie24 you can always re-implement those templates if you prefer.

Comment: Is memcpying to a long long really allowed? I feel like that breaks some kind of c++ rule.

Comment: @acidzombie24 I'm fairly sure it is. Do you have any particular rule in mind that you have feelings about?